# Type clash on update of always encrypted varchar in ssms 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, always-encrypted

I am using SSMS 17.6 and I am trying out the Always Encrypted feature.
I was able to update/insert/search a datetime field by declaring a parameter and then using the parameter, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @NewValue datetime 
SET @NewValue = '19/05/2018' 
update MyTable set my_ae_column = @NewValue
```

I am trying doing the same for a varchar(30) field for which bin2 collation is set, but I still get the

> Operand type clash issue

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to do a bunch of things first. Have you followed every single thing in [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I did, that's why I was able to update a datetime encrypted column. My issue is with the varchar column (also encrypted).

Comment: Show your code that fails (instead of the code that works!) and the table structure. If you just use `varchar` for example it's going to break; if you use `varchar(10)` but the column is `varchar(20)` it's going to break; if you use `DECLARE` and `SET` separately (like in your question) it's going to break.

Comment: The structure is varchar(30) as well as the declared variable...mindblowing

Comment: Again, show your code, and we might be able to help identify what is wrong. If you're not willing to show your code, we have to guess at a possible answer, like I did... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are not checking the following from [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/), which states that you can't use `DECLARE` and `SET` separately:

> Declared and initialized in the same statement (inline initialization). SSMS will not parameterize variables declared using separate SET statements.

I get the same error you get when I write code *like* what you have in the question. This is why we ask for **the code that breaks**, not **the code that works** (though I doubt the code you wrote in your question works either!):

```
DECLARE @column nvarchar(30);
SET @column = N'whatever';
UPDATE ...
```

It works just fine when I declare the variable and assign it immediately, like this:

```
DECLARE @column nvarchar(30) = N'whatever';
UPDATE ...
```

This mismatch can happen for a variety of other reasons, of course. Such as not setting your connection to `column encryption setting = enabled`, not enabling the "Enable Paramterization..." setting in SSMS, using a function or expression when declaring and assigning the variable, using the wrong data type or length or precision or scale, etc. We could help narrow that down if you **include the code that breaks**.